# CDF's of Two Binomial Distributions with the Same Mean and Different Probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have two binomial random variables $X_i \sim B(\frac{a}{p_i},p_i)$ and $X_j \sim B(\frac{a}{p_j},p_j)$, where $a$ is a positive integer, and both $\frac{a}{p_i}$ and $\frac{a}{p_j}$ are integers. Assume $p_i > p_j$. In particular, we have $E[X_i] = E[X_j] = a$.

Let $F_{X_i} (x)$ and $F_{X_j} (x)$ denote the CDF's of $X_i$ and $X_j$, respectively. It seems true (with an example in the image below) that $F_{X_i} (x) < F_{X_j} (x)$ for $x < a$ and $F_{X_i} (x) > F_{X_j} (x)$ for $x > a$. Is there a simple way to prove it (or, is this result somewhat established in literature)?

[image]

Comment: Thank you @muccilolo for the feedback. 

I suggest tackling this problem equivalently as: 

"If $p_i>p_i$, does $P\{|X_i-a|>k\}\geq P\{|X_j-a|\geq k\}$ hold for all $k$?" 

Intuitively, since $\sigma_i^2<\sigma_j^2$, it should. I tried bounding the probabilities using Slud's and Hoeffding's inequalities, but I couldn't work it out. Then I suspected that the claim only holds in a vicinity of $a$. But it seems that I cannot find a counterexample either. Anyway, I suggest looking for upper and lower bounds.

Also, thank you amWhy, Leucippus, John B, and G. Chiusole.

Comment: The question got answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380215/cdfs-of-two-binomial-distributions-with-the-same-mean-and-different-probabiliti. Thanks everyone for helping!